# Is iced coffeescript supporting or going to support promises?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, promise, iced-coffeescript

As a node.js practitioner, I am actively using coffeescript and functions based on [promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). Recently I have found out [iced coffeescript](http://maxtaco.github.io/coffee-script/), and I wonder whether my approach can go along with "iced await defer" one.

So here is my question, **is there any support for the promises implemented or planned for the iced coffeescript**? Or would rather iced coffeescript made me come back to the callback functions world?

Also as a side question, as far as my knowledge goes, there is an ECMAscript 7 draft to introduce await async patten to solve the issue. Is iced coffeescript team planning to blend on it if it will become standard?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iced CoffeeScript development has stagnated lately. I regard ICS as interesting experiment - given its current adoption I would not really recommend using it. As for support or planned support there is none - there might be in the future but the issue tracker shows no issues discussing it have been opened.

ECMAScript 7 indeed has async functions - since those use promises there is no reason to assume any work is done in ICS to support them. Again - no one can tell the future and there might be work on those at a future point in time.

Answer (score 4):

Iced is certainly active and in many cases (like parallel calls) is more flexible than promises.  There is now an open PR for ES7 `async` at [maxtaco/coffee-script#147](https://github.com/maxtaco/coffee-script/pull/147), and is far more simple than the open PRs on regular Coffee (#3757, #3813).

The easiest way to use Iced with Promises is to [`nodeify`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#nodeifyfunction-callback--object-options---promise) the Promise.  I use many Promise-based libs in my Iced code without trouble.

I think most coders using Iced just far prefer the clean syntax of await/defer over promises.  A major advantage of using Iced now, is that the Iced code that works now will also work in the future, despite whatever underlying changes happen in ES6/7 and Coffee implementations as syntax is finalized.

Comment: It seems like it would be fairly easy to implement that nodeify wrapper directly into ICS.